# Nodejs Httpclient JSONP: jsonCallback is not defined

Tags: angular, callback, httpclient, jsonp

I am not able to work around this problem with JSONP. I have the following service in Angular 7.3.8:

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpClient, HttpClientJsonpModule } from '@angular/common/http';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs';
 
import { Station } from '../models';
 
@Injectable()
export class RevisionService { 

   baseURL : string = "https://opendata.euskadi.eus/contenidos/ds_informes_estudios/calidad_aire_2020/es_def/adjuntos/estaciones.json";
 
   constructor(private http:HttpClient){
   }
 
   getStations(): Observable<Station[]> {
      return this.http.jsonp<Station[]>(this.baseURL, 'jsonCallback');
   }
}
```

The function getStations just returns an *observable* of a custom object.

When I try to acces the JSONP code, however, I get the following console error each and every time:

```
jsonCallback is not defined at ...estaciones.json?jsonCallback=ng_jsonp_callback_0:1
```

While the httpclient response is the following:

```
Http failure response for https://opendata.euskadi.eus/contenidos/ds_informes_estudios/calidad_aire_2020/es_def/adjuntos/estaciones.json?jsonCallback=ng_jsonp_callback_0: 0 JSONP Error
```

I have tried many solutions proposed here in stackoverflow, such as appending `jsonCallback=JSONP_CALLBACK` to the URL, switching the callback argument between `jsonCallback`, `callback`, etc. to no avail. It looks as if the httpclient just ignored my callback argument.

Any ideas on how to proceed?

Comment: you should seek through opendata.euskadi.eus and find how the jsonp callback param should be called. the default one as you understood is `jsonCallback`. but it shouldnt work like that. with normal jsonp the client application chooses how the jsonp callback is called. when you find how the param is called pass it as a second parameter to `this.http.jsonp(url, callbackName)`

Comment: @Andrei If you check the json file I put on the code, you can see it starts with that `jsonCallback`. Maybe I lost something along the way, but I think using that name should suffice.